# TenantAccessor in NEO

Tags: s4sdk

I have tried to use the TenantAccessor in NEO environment.
The resulting TenantId from TenantAccessor.getCurrentTenant().getTenantId() is returned as GUID. However, in NEO, I am not able to map the GUID to an subaccount. The expectation was to get the subaccount name.

Please let me know the difference between the meaning of subaccount and tenant.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with relying on the account name is that there is - as of today -  no definitive contract on the uniqueness of the account name on SAP Cloud Platform Neo. While the relationship between the tenant identifier and the account name is typically a 1:1 relationship, this is not guaranteed to be enforced for historic reasons. Therefore, Neo offers a unique tenant identifier in addition to the account name.

If you still need to get the account name on SAP Cloud Platform Neo, you can retrieve it via the [`TenantContext`](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/javadoc/com/sap/cloud/account/TenantContext.html) which is available for Neo:

```java
Tenant currentTenant = TenantAccessor.getCurrentTenant();

// assert that we are running on SAP Cloud Platform Neo
if( !(currentTenant instanceof ScpNeoTenant) ) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected SAP Cloud Platform environment.");
}

// get the Neo-specific TenantContext
TenantContext tenantContext = ((ScpNeoTenant)currentTenant).getTenantContext();
String accountName = tenantContext.getTenant().getAccount().getName();
```